# Sendsms plugin not working on Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to send a message using The "Sendsms"plugin for phone gap on Android. 
But when I call the function, I get this error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'send' of undefined at file
```

This is the JS code I'm using :

```
              function onDeviceReady () {
        $('#send').bind('click', function () {
            alert('Phone: ' + $('#friendName').val() + ' Message: ' +       $('#MessageContent').val());
            window.plugins.sms.send($('#friendName').val(), 
                $('#MessageContent').val(), 
                function () { 
                   alert('Message sent successfully');  
                },
                function (e) {
                    alert('Message Failed:' + e);
                }
            );
        });                         
    }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

I got the java code from [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/SMSPlugin/src/net/practicaldeveloper/phonegap/plugins/SmsPlugin.java) & added the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

And added the plugin to Plugins.xml.

Do you know what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what version of PhoneGap you are using you may just have to go into the smsplugin.js and replace the instances of "PhoneGap" with "cordova".