# phonegap 1.7.0 plugins android not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, applicationcraft

I'm programming an android app using Applicationcraft, but then I need to create my own plugin for a certain requirement. So I downloaded my app from applicationcraft, then compile it manual using phonegap 1.7.0, but I'm having a problem with my plugin. I have followed every steps in this [tutorial](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android), but whenever I use my plugin in a test device I always get this error:

Cannot call method "myfunction" of undefined.
Function: callingFunction

I also consult another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397210/sendsms-plugin-not-working-on-phonegap), but I still having the same problem.

**Can anybody tell me what are the possible solutions?** Or point me to the right direction (any tutorial for making plugin for PhoneGap 1.7.0). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need, I've already found it [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html).